# How to configure Nautilus in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, nautilus

While trying to use Nautilus as primary file manager for Xfce I noticed that it seems impossible to reach the preferences menu in Xfce.

On a normal Ubuntu installation with GNOME or similar it is reachable by using the menu in the top bar under the File section.

The problem is that Xfce and KDE don't have such a bar, and it seems that the application menu is not showing anywhere. Is this normal, and is there a way to get around this (with the same keyboard shortcut or another)?

It works as it is, but it's not configurable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf-editor (part of the dconf-tools package) and traverse to org>gnome>nautilus. 
All of nautilus' configuration settings are stored there and can be changed as required.